# Change global variable in Python in another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, variables

I want change global variable in module1.py by module2.py.

*module1.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading
import module2  as module22
import time

values=True

def main():
 print "m"


def thread():
 while(values):
  print "moduel1"
  time.sleep(0.50)
 print "END PROGRAM"

def change():
 print "change"
 values=False

if __name__ == "__main__":

 t2=threading.Thread(target=module22.main())
 t1=threading.Thread(target=thread())



 t1.start()
 t2.start()


 t1.join()
 t2.join()
```

*module2.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import module1 as module11


def main():
 print "module2"

 module11.change()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

When I run sudo python module1.py:

***Result is here***

```
module2
change
moduel1
moduel1..
```

***I want get result***

```
 module2
 change
 END PROGRAM
```

Comment: is this working? you have a mutual import in your modules....

Comment: Thank you Daniel Sanchez for the reaction.Yes the program works.
But not so  As I need. Mutal import is problems?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare values as global, if you dont do this, the variable is handled as new local variable.

```
def change():
  global values
  print "change"
  values=False
```

Comment: Thanks Frank Landgraf I tried yours solutions but No 
its not working